# Is there an algorithm that stores the values of the sub-grids of a two-dimensional array into a new two-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays

I am solving a problem that asks me to stores the values of sub-grids of a 4x4 two-dimensional array into a new 4x4 two-dimensional array

What I mean about the sub-grids are the four element at the four corners

For instance:
Original array:

```
[
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
[9,10,11,12]
[13,14,15,16]
]
```

The top-right sub-grid is [1,2,5,6], top-left one is [3,4,7,8]...etc

And here is the new array after the conversion:

```
[
[1,2,5,6]
[3,4,7,8]
[9,10,13,14]
[11,12,15,16]
]
```

I'd like to know if there's an algorithm that does this conversion or if there is any way that I can do it using a nested loop, thank you

Comment: Is it always gonna be a 4x4 array? If so, there is a trivial way of doing this as it's all about swapping 2 pairs of values really

Comment: Yes, but would you mind being more specifically? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be a 4x4 array, then the algorithm can be as simple as this:

```js
const a = [
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [9,10,11,12],
  [13,14,15,16]
];

const res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i+=2) {
    res.push([ a[i][0], a[i][1], a[i+1][0], a[i+1][1] ]);
    res.push([ a[i][2], a[i][3], a[i+1][2], a[i+1][3] ]);
}

console.log(res);
```